# How can I use ISAPI-Rewrite to rewrite a URL only when rewritten target URL exists?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, seo, isapi-rewrite

Or the opposite, how can I rewrite a URL only if it does not exist?  eg, intercept 404s.

Here's the context: We are slowly migrating our site from ASP classic to ASP.NET.  By slowly, I mean converting 9000+ .asp pages one page at a time to .aspx.

While doing this we want to prevent any broken links as well as avoid losing any rankings in the search engines.  That means all our .asp URLs must continue to exist even though they would be served by .aspx pages.

What I would like to be able to do is have ISAPI-Rewrite rule(s) that will rewrite .asp -> .aspx unless the target URL does not actually exist in which case it would just execute and return the .asp.

So if we haven't converted somepage.asp to .aspx yet, the URL would not get rewritten and somepage.asp would be displayed.  Once somepage.asp is gone the URL would be rewritten to somepage.aspx which would be executed and returned, but the web browser/search engine would think that it received somepage.asp.

At some point in the future we would set the [canonical url](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) in the .aspx pages and let the search engines catch up at their convenience.

Note: I have experimented with using a custom 404 on IIS to check the file system and do a Server.Transfer if the target .aspx page exists, however you cannot transfer from asp classic to asp.net.  ( You get "The specified 'Page Language="c#" ' option is unknown or invalid. error '8000d001'" )  The only way this would work is if we did a 301/302 redirect instead of the Server.Transfer and that is undesirable for us at this time. (Management is paranoid and says not an option.)

Comment: In order to detect a 404 a web request needs to be made and that's something that ISApi-Rewrite won't do for you. The only way that I can think of doing this is to manually add you ASP files to the ini file one at a time as you convert them.

Comment: Or if things are in folders (hopefully for 9,000+ page site they are) then you can do it 1 folder at a time.

Comment: @Chris There are indeed many folders, however some of them contain many thousands of pages making it unrealistic given staff and time constraints for us to be able to commit to doing an entire directory at once.

Comment: @Chris Are you saying that ISAPI Rewrite cannot be used to rewrite URLs that would otherwise result in a 404?  Hmm... what if our 404 page was a 404.aspx and not our usual 404.asp...

Comment: Sorry @Hellfire, long weekend. ISAPI Rewrite never sees status codes unfortunately, only clients see those. You can definitely use a 404.aspx page to catch everything else, that's what I do on all of my sites. Because you're running mixed-mode though the only way that I can think of for sending a classic ASP page back without redirecting is to actually make the request on the server-side and output HTML. Definitely not the most ideal thing to do but it should work. You'd have to make sure that you send cookies along, too.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you telnet to the server and manually check the status codes for each possible scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  As Chris Haas suggested, if I make my 404 handler an .aspx page, then I am able to do a Server.Transfer when the target page exists and if not, just fall through and let the regular 404 status be returned.  So something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script RunAt="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String requestedUrl = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"];

        if (requestedUrl.EndsWith(".asp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            String targetUrl = requestedUrl + "x";
            String targetPath = Server.MapPath(targetUrl);

            if (File.Exists(targetPath)) {
                Server.Transfer(targetUrl);
            }
        }
        Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
    }

</script>
```

I still need to test it with querystrings but so far it handles each case perfectly.  When the time comes and management is okay with it, we'll simply stop doing the Server.Transfer and change it to a 301 Moved Permanently.  With IIS able to set error pages per directory, we can even be somewhat selective about when we do it.

Incidentally, it looks like ISAPI_Rewrite 3 might have a file checking option that could also have worked but we only have v2 on our server.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if the content is moving you would want to write a process that does a 301 redirect to indicate that the page was moved to a new location.  As that is truly the case.

This would ensure that the new content gets indexed and linked appropriately.

Comment: 301/302 redirect is not an option due to management's unwillingness to risk our rankings.

Comment: There's big difference between 301 and 302, the first is permanent, the second is temporary. 301 should preserve your rankings, as well as informing the SE that the content location has moved, so they'll hopefully update their index to your new location.

Comment: @James It's the "hopefully" that has them putting the restrictions on this and the reason I'm asking for a different way.